# Jquery .mouseenter() event is very much faster than .click() or .mousedown() events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly large html page and I've noticed that my click-to-show/hide process appears a little retarded.

I've also discovered that if I use "mouseenter" in place of "click", the response is almost instantaneous (as opposed to 2 seconds when I use "click").

```
$("button.showhide").click(function() { $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"-1").toggle() });

versus

$("button.showhide").mouseenter(function() { $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"-1").toggle() });
```

Is there any way to make the click event as fast as the mouseenter event?

Thanks.

Edit:
Does the following help in explaining this behaviour?
(There's no mention of a "javascript event" for mouseenter.)

.click()
Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

.mousedown()
Bind an event handler to the "mousedown" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

.mouseenter()
Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

Comment: Did you try the `.mousedown` event? A click is triggered after releasing the mouse button, so the order of events is `mousedown` -> `mouseup` -> `click`.

Comment: Yes, I did try the mousedown event but it is just as slow as the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate to trigger your events(from jQuery 1.7 use `on` method for events binding) :

```
$("button").on('click','.showhide',function(){/*...*/});
```

You could improve the speed of the event handling, but that depends on the html markup.
For instance, if all of your `showhide` buttons are grouped in a certain div, and some other buttons are in other scattered all over the body, you should use something like this :

```
$("button-container-selector").on('click','button.showhide',function(){/*...*/});
```

Comment: This is exactly what he is doing

Comment: the second example illustrates better how delegates should improve your event-handling response speed

Comment: yes the second example is better, but it doesn't explain why the mouseenter event is fast and the click event is "slow", because the OP used the same selector for both event handlers

Answer (score 0):

I think that the time to process

```
function() { $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"-1").toggle();
```

is exactly the same in the two cases, it's just that mouseenter triggers much earlier than click and so you think it's faster.

The only thing i could think of is that you have realy a lot of click handlers, but i think you really nead a lot to slow down things

EDIT - Try doing

```
$('body').on("click", "button.showhide", function() { $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"-1").toggle());
```

Comment: Afraid not. The difference is between 2 seconds and instantaneous response.

Comment: @user918081 the same function can't have different executing times...if the click it's "longer" is because it takes more time to call the function, not to execute it

Comment: But that's what I'm observing. I did a test where I inserted an alert statement as the very first statement of the function. For the "mouseenter" event, I see the alert msgbox straightaway. For the "click" event, the msgbox popped up 2 seconds later. Something in the backend appears to be holding back "click"?

Comment: @user918081 probably you have too many event handlers. How many `button.showhide` elements are there?Is there no container object for them?try the code i posted now (i assume you use jQuery 1.7 or greater

Comment: I've tried your code but unfortunately, things didn't change. There are indeed a lot of button.showhide elements. But in a like-for-like situation, I'm still curious about why "mouseenter" is so much faster.

Answer (score 0):

By reading all previous answers, and the behaviour explained in the question, I think that there might have been a key piece of information missing. Was your test was happening in a tablet or a touch-enabled device by any chance?

Some touch-enabled browsers or devices will slow down click events to allow for a delay, so the user can start a gesture instead of issuing a click. This would explain why, in your case, "mousedown" or "click" are slower than "mouseenter", which in a touch device happens as soon as you touch the element being monitored.

If this is the case, what I would do to improve responsiveness and be compatible in different types of devices, is binding both "mousedown" and "touchstart" (compatible with touch-enabled devices) to the code that must  execute after the mouse press (or screen touch).

In your case:

```
$("button.showhide").bind('touchstart mousedown', function() {
    $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"-1").toggle()
});
```

I hope this helps.